# How to find parts in OrCAD / Allegro

Tags: library, orcad

I probably spend most of my time in OrCAD / Allegro schematic capture just trying to find relatively simple parts.  I'm assuming I'm missing something critical, as I've never had any formal training on the software.

For example, if I'm trying to find a Zener diode, in which library do I look?  This goes for all sorts of simple circuit building blocks.  For passives (caps, resistors, etc) I just use the pSpice components, is this the correct way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Are you designing a PCB eventually? Or simply doing schematic capture for documentation/simulation/etc? For many of these types of questions, the canonical answer is "make it yourself".

Comment: Eventually a PCB will be designed. I'm not sure if I will do it with allegro or if someone else will do it in another suite. Another problem I am looking at are quad pack op amps that aren't in the library. For schematic clarity, I would like to show each amp individually. Is this easy to achieve in the part editor?

Comment: Yes, there should be a way to make a component which contains four op-amps, but only one is placed at a time (with a letter suffix, typically).

Answer (score 3):

During this process of selecting a part or a library, for PCB and not simulation always add the discrete library.  This has the most common parts.  After OrCad project has been completed, when you open the place a part menu or "p" on the keyboard, you can type a part number or a part type like zener, it will search all libraries and tell you which one it is (library) add the library, select the part and place it.  If you create custom schematic images or modify one in the library, add them to a new library, updates can over write standard libraries and your custom will be lost.  You will have to go to a schematic that used the part and recover it from there.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Having the same problem I built this OrCAD to EXCEL part list. Here is a link to my GitHub https://github.com/FredCailloux/OrCAD-stuff I propose a CaptureEXCELcomplete.zip file.

In that zip file you will find all OrCAD Capture libraries in an EXCEL format. Each Capture library content is there in it's corresponding EXCEL file. All files are presented in Folder Sub-Folder arrangement identical as the one present in the Capture\libraries\ installation folder.

To quickly find where a part may be in a library all you have to do is UnZip the file on your local drive (make sure that particular folder in within Windows Indexing location) and then open Windows Explorer, navigate to where you unzipped the file and use the Windows Explorer Search feature. With each character you enter in the search field you will see exactly in which library you can find that search string.

Furthermore, you can use those EXCEL files to build a MS ACCESS database for other uses.

Hope this help

Cheers

Comment: "-1 down vote" - are you certain you would like a down vote ?

Comment: Not sure how this -1 comes from. Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: Oh I do not know. Your answer starts with those words "-1 down vote". To me it just looks you want us to down vote this answer :)